# Infinite loop to fade away a div to reveal div underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's which are absolute positioned to sit on top of each other. I'm just looking to create a simple jQuery function which fades away the div on top (.group-fcallout-b) to reveal the one underneath (.group-fcallout-a).

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    InfiniteRotator();
});

function InfiniteRotator() {

  var fadeO = setInterval(function() {
    $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeOut(500);
  }, 5000);

  clearInterval(InfiniteRotator);

  var fadeI = setInterval(function() {
    $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeIn(500);
  }, 5000);
}
```

I think the issue I'm having at the moment is that fadeIn starts immediately after fadeOut has finished - obviously I want a delay between the two functions.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/02xLjh1y/11/

Many thanks!

Comment: So call fadeIn when the fadeOut is complete?

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36180931/4864063) below - when in doubt, jQuery usually already has a built in method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a one liner:

```
setInterval(function(){ $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeToggle(500); }, 5000)
```

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02xLjh1y/24/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to achieve what I think is your goal ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/02xLjh1y/21/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  InfiniteRotator(jQuery.fn.fadeOut, jQuery.fn.fadeIn);
});

function InfiniteRotator(fadeFunc, callback) {
    fadeFunc.call($('.group-fcallout-b'), 500, function() {
      setTimeout(function() { InfiniteRotator(callback, fadeFunc); }, 1000);
    });
}
```

[Edit: added a timeout before fading back the other way]

Since both fadeIn and fadeOut take an optional callback argument, you can exploit this instead of using `setInterval`.

N.B. I don't know whether you care or not, but the use of a capital 'I' in `InfiniteRotator` is a bit unusual - normally the capital letter would tend to imply that this is a constructor function, which it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your solution - and yes the capital I is a typo XD The problem with this is that I need it to pause on each of the div blocks before it fades in/out. Basically akin to a carousel except that it fades instead of scrolling (and it'll only ever be these two blocks).

Comment: I've updated the answer and the fiddle - is that what you mean?

Comment: That's brilliant - thank you :) As an additional, is there a way to set a delay before the fade occurs? Literally so that if there were several of these on the page they don't all fade at the same time ( I can amend it to work with several blocks, I just need help with the delay x3 ).

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct for you ? 
[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02xLjh1y/14/)

I changed value of timeout in the second one.

```
  var fadeO = setInterval(function() {
    $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeOut(500);
  }, 5000);

  clearInterval(InfiniteRotator);

  var fadeI = setInterval(function() {
    $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeIn(500);
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work - but I can't help but feel there must be a better solution XD

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/gb0tw6ru/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    InfiniteRotator();

});

function InfiniteRotator() {
    var flag = 1;

    var fadeOut = function() {
        $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeOut(500);
        flag = 0;
    }

    var fadeIn = function() {
        $('.group-fcallout-b').fadeIn(500);
        flag = 1;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(flag)
            fadeOut();
        else
            fadeIn();
    }, 5000);
}
```